# Columns with content align keep last div aligned to bottom?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 columns with content and I managed to align the last div to bottom, by giving a fixed height to the column. Is there a better method since this won't work if someone will change the content, add more text or less text.

```
.column {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
}
.btn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

My Fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkms1c05/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Flexbox layout is a good solution.

The `body` element has row layout (it contains the 3 columns), each column has column layout (obvious). and inside the column the content grows to fill the space remaining.

I removed the absolute positioning from the `.btn` class, so it would take the space inside the coulmn.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  min-height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.btn {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iure repudiandae asperiores obcaecati accusantium, sapiente, tenetur dolores fugit omnis repellat dolorem iusto mollitia recusandae quidem perspiciatis dolore, ipsum suscipit ab?
  </div>
  <div class="btn">Click Me!</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iure repudiandae asperiores obcaecati accusantium, sapiente, tenetur dolores fugit omnis repellat dolorem iusto mollitia recusandae quidem perspiciatis dolore, ipsum suscipit ab? Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iure repudiandae asperiores obcaecati accusantium, sapiente, tenetur dolores fugit omnis repellat dolorem iusto mollitia recusandae quidem perspiciatis dolore, ipsum suscipit ab?
  </div>
  <div class="btn">Click Me!</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iure repudiandae asperiores obcaecati accusantium, sapiente, tenetur dolores fugit omnis repellat dolorem iusto mollitia recusandae quidem perspiciatis dolore, ipsum suscipit ab?
  </div>
  <div class="btn">Click Me!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need with fixed height for columns.

Here is the code

```css
.column {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative; 
}
.btn {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    
}
.content{background:#f5f5f5;height:240px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;}
```

```html
<div class="column">
       <div class="title">
       <h2>Title 1</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="content">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iure repudiandae asperiores obcaecati accusantium, sapiente, tenetur dolores fugit omnis repellat dolorem iusto mollitia recusandae quidem perspiciatis dolore, ipsum suscipit ab?
       </div>
       <div class="btn">Click Me!</div>
   </div>
    
    <div class="column">
       <div class="title">
           <h2>Title 2</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="content">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iure repudiandae asperiores obcaecati accusantium, sapiente, tenetur dolores fugit omnis repellat dolorem iusto mollitia recusandae quidem perspiciatis dolore, ipsum suscipit ab?
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iure repudiandae asperiores obcaecati accusantium, sapiente, tenetur dolores fugit omnis repellat dolorem iusto mollitia recusandae quidem perspiciatis dolore, ipsum suscipit ab?
       </div>
       <div class="btn">Click Me!</div>
   </div>
    
    <div class="column">
       <div class="title">
           <h2>Title 3</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="content">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iure repudiandae asperiores obcaecati accusantium, sapiente, tenetur dolores fugit omnis repellat dolorem iusto mollitia recusandae quidem perspiciatis dolore, ipsum suscipit ab?
       </div>
       <div class="btn">Click Me!</div>
   </div>
```

Otherwise if you want to last div always bottom to above elements not as fixed.

Here is the code->

```css
.column {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    height: auto;
    position: relative; 
}
.btn {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    
}
.content{background:#f5f5f5;}
```

```html
<div class="column">
       <div class="title">
       <h2>Title 1</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="content">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iure repudiandae asperiores obcaecati accusantium, sapiente, tenetur dolores fugit omnis repellat dolorem iusto mollitia recusandae quidem perspiciatis dolore, ipsum suscipit ab?
       </div>
       <div class="btn">Click Me!</div>
   </div>
    
    <div class="column">
       <div class="title">
           <h2>Title 2</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="content">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iure repudiandae asperiores obcaecati accusantium, sapiente, tenetur dolores fugit omnis repellat dolorem iusto mollitia recusandae quidem perspiciatis dolore, ipsum suscipit ab?
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iure repudiandae asperiores obcaecati accusantium, sapiente, tenetur dolores fugit omnis repellat dolorem iusto mollitia recusandae quidem perspiciatis dolore, ipsum suscipit ab?
       </div>
       <div class="btn">Click Me!</div>
   </div>
    
    <div class="column">
       <div class="title">
           <h2>Title 3</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="content">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iure repudiandae asperiores obcaecati accusantium, sapiente, tenetur dolores fugit omnis repellat dolorem iusto mollitia recusandae quidem perspiciatis dolore, ipsum suscipit ab?
       </div>
       <div class="btn">Click Me!</div>
   </div>
```